# Norm of Hilbert space Gaussian

Tags: probability, hilbert-spaces

Let $X$ be a random variable with values in a separable Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ with inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$. Assume that $X$ has a Gaussian distribution in the sense that

$$
\langle X, h\rangle 
$$

is Gaussian for every $h \in \mathcal{H}$. We define the expectation of $X$ as the element $\mu \in \mathcal{H}$ such that

$$
E(\langle X, h \rangle) = \langle \mu, h \rangle \quad \forall h \in \mathcal{H}
$$

and the covariance operator as the Hilbert-Schmidt operator, $C$, from $\mathcal{H}$ to $\mathcal{H}$ given by

$$
\langle Cf ,g \rangle = E ( \langle X, f \rangle \langle X, g \rangle) - \langle \mu, f \rangle \langle \mu, g \rangle
$$

What is the distribution of $\lVert X \rVert^2 = \langle X, X \rangle$? Does it even have a distribution? Can we express it using the mean and covariance?

Comment: Since $X$ is measurable and $h\mapsto \|h\|^2$ is continuous, $\|X\|^2$ is again measurable. So of course, $\|X\|^2$ *has* a distribution. It's still a good question what that distribution is. Maybe, it helps to look at the finite dimensional case first in order to get an idea of what happens. [This](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/155829/euclidian-norm-of-gaussian-vectors) might be a good place to start looking.